# Biking Target Speeds

Tags: road-bike, speed

On a road bike what is a good target solo speed for someone who wants to be a better than average cyclist?

Like is there a certain speed where you know as a cyclist you are doing pretty good like 20 MPH+ for an extended period of time?

What is the speed and duration in time/distance one would need to be able to sustain in order to consider semi-pro racing (male rider)?

Comment: Faster than the bear who's chasing you.

Comment: @DanielRHicks is that the Bear with the Hammer?  Or a bear driving the broom wagon ?

Comment: Question is much too broad for a good answer, so many things can have an impact.  Road surface, altitude, hills/flat, bike/wheels, all out effort or easy.

Comment: Get a power meter. Above ~4W/kg FTP you’ll probably get a podium in local races, assuming you have good material (and setup). Above ~5W/kg you are in pro territory.

Comment: @DanielRHicks *Faster than the bear who's chasing you.*  Naaah, you don't have to be faster than the bear.  You just need to be faster than at least one other rider.  Whack 'em in the leg with your frame pump!

Comment: @DanielRHicks bears are freakishly fast, they can keep at 40 mph for minutes. You’ve got no chance on a push bike :)

Comment: I agree with Michael regarding a power meter, although websites like Strava can estimate power from weight and slope (and can you record your ride with a phone) so you may want to look at that as a first step (you may have to be a paid subscriber for the power feature). Also good cyclists maintain high cadence (pedal speed), at least 80rpm or higher. Working on power and cadence is probably more effective than on speed, although the odd sprint does wonders for fitness.

Comment: On a flat course, try to ride 37-40km in an hour solo. That's nothing to sniff at 

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov adrenaline can work wonders, I’ve chased down car drivers at 40mph+ over a couple of km and I’m a decidedly unexceptional cyclist. (Not a good idea BTW, when the drivers stopped I found I no longer had legs or lungs which makes it hard to explain anything let alone rant or run away if things go pear-shaped.)

Answer (score 13):

I agree with Criggie's answer, but there's another way to look at it. Speed is mostly a function of power output. And you can quantify a cyclist's fitness in terms of their power-to-weight ratio, that is, W/kg.

[This article](https://www.cyclinganalytics.com/blog/2018/06/how-does-your-cycling-power-output-compare) shows what cyclists of different levels can produce in terms of W/kg, how long they can maintain different levels of output, etc. There's a lot there.

You can take that information and plug it into [this calculator](https://www.gribble.org/cycling/power_v_speed.html) to estimate speed based on power and other conditions. You'll note that it takes a lot of additional power to go just a little faster.

Comment: ...and noone should feel that they have to perform at any specific level, before entering a race.  A beginner's event is full of all sorts of riders.

Comment: @Criggie I'll have to disagree with that some.  If you can't hold a good line, don't know how to corner in a pack, and don't have much experience riding in ***fast*** groups, please don't show up for an actual sanctioned-by-your-national-authority-under-UCI road race.  If you can't ride safely in a tight pack at speed around sharp corners, you're an actual danger to yourself and everyone else riding.   10 riders eating pavement and bike parts at 40 kph because some !(*&%!#@ adrenaline-hyped noob thinks dive-bombing a corner is faster is not a good thing.

Comment: Certainly there is a lot more that goes into success in bike racing than raw power—reading the course, reading other riders, willingness to suffer, bike handling, optimizing your training, etc. But I think those are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: The Johnstone article doesn't say specifically, but I think he must be defining power as the mechanical work done on the pedals. This is fine, but you have to keep in mind that this differs by an order of magnitude from the food energy consumed. I would argue that food energy is a nicer measure for many purposes, because it allows comparisons to be made with other sports, such as running. Pedal power is apparently about 5 W/kg for elite cyclists, whereas food energy consumption is about 21 W/kg for Eliud Kipchoge when he runs a marathon in two hours: https://github.com/bcrowell/stoke

Comment: @AndrewHenle while I agree that a complete newbie shouldn't enter a cat1 race and get in the way of experienced riders, there's definitely a need to learn those skills either by casual group rides or entry-level races.  Noone should feel they can't start racing, and OP implies they want to do well on their first race.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: a UCI sanctioned race isn't going to let a newbie in such a race to begin with, regardless how fast the new racer is or claims to be. They'll have to start in Cat5 like everyone else.

Comment: @whatsisname not in the UK.  Unfortunately we don't have Cat5 here in the UK.  The end result is beginner/new racers being thrown amongst fast/fit racers.  A typical entry level UCI sanctioned race here will average between 37-45kmh and require skills for riding in a fast bunch

Answer (score 8):

There's no one fixed answer.

In racing, there are categories, around 5 normally.  A category 5 racer is someone who is entering their first couple races, possibly has a road bike though its not unknown for MTBs to be used.

Once you have some race completions, then you can be placed in the next category.  Depending on the body organising races, you may need to achieve a top 3 place in 2 of your last 5 races, or something similar.

To win or place, you have to finish the race course faster than most of the rest of the competitors (in your category).  Its common for several categories to run at the same time, to get the best use of daylight.

If the race is a 20 minute sprint/crit, then the speeds needed will be higher than a 10 hour/200 km endurance race.

If you want to participate in a race, **just do it** - is that simple.

If you want to win a race, you have to enter, and if you've never raced before then simply crossing the START line is an achievement.  Aim to cross the Finish line too, even if you're dead-last its still better than a DNF or a DNS/scratch.

Since you really seem to be asking for a target number, I'd estimate that a flat ride of 24 km should take you no more than 1 hour in neutral winds, ergo an average speed of 24 km/h (15 mph) would be a good target.

If you need a rest in that hour, you're pushing too hard and need to work on your endurance.  If you're wrecked after that hour's effort then that's okay, aim for shorter races.  Also, that same 24km/h effort will get you at least 20% more, or 30+km/h in a bunch.  That's a weird but neat feeling.

For more local advise, try searching for cycle races near you.  I see that https://localraces.com/ returns about 4 relevant clubs.  Just call and ask about events or group rides.

---

If you've never ridden in a group, its probably wise to get some practice in before trying a race.  Being able to ride in a paceline, smoothly and safely is a skill in itself.  This is another area where a club can be useful.

Comment: If you're of the mindset that "I'm only going to enter a race when I can win it" then you'll never feel up to starting.

Comment: Also, do use Strava to log your rides, and look at the segments.  See other riders and how fast they're going on their best days (which are frequently stompingly good tail winds)

Comment: Seems like you have much better entry level racing than we do here in Scotland.  Our entry/beginner level races can be pushing 40km/h

Comment: @AndyP yep that's a barrier-to-entry right there.   Also called "gatekeeping"   Here's my first real race   https://www.strava.com/activities/520613679/analysis  with an average speed overall of 20.8 km/h  AND I got beaten to the end by a middle age guy on a 3 speed upright bike.  My final time was ~3/4 of the way down the list.  But I achieved the primary goal of finishing, and the secondary goal of being not last.   My next year's effort was slower at 20.2 km/h average but I got a better overall time, which was that year's goal.   Frankly the hardest thing about your first race is starting.

Comment: @AndyP I would suggest to that club that they think about being more approachable, run some starter races for those who are interested.  Would help bolster club membership with new blood.

Comment: OP might also like to consider the kind of race that doesn't involve riding in a group and won't involve getting dropped if you can't keep up the pace... no barriers to entry whatsoever (and I think are popular for "trying out racing" for exactly that reason) and allows you know find out EXACTLY where you stand in relation to other riders...

Comment: To give you some idea, the peak of my cycling performance was only as a mediocre Cat 2/3 rider in the 70s and 80s. 
At my best i could survive within a bunch on a 80 km race, more usually i got dropped and rode on solo until either the finish or a convenient place. So I took up time trialling instead in England and Australia.
As a mid 20s to mid 30s guy I could achieve 16 km in about 25 mins, 40 km in 65 mins, 80 km in 2 hrs 20, and 160 km in 5 hrs 5 mins. I wasn't usually last, and was beaten by both men and women, some aged in their 40s and 50s. That is one snapshot of mediocre!

Comment: @Criggie Looked at linked ride, and in the UK that type of ride is covered by the sportive market, which are generally timed, and treated by many as races, but not actually classified as races.  Overall, we have a problem with too few actual races on the calendar = many people with cat2/3 power profiles racing entry level races simply because they don't score enough points to move up.

Comment: "slower at 20.2 km/h average but I got a better overall time" - do cyclists not define average speed as distance/time? I'm puzzled as to how you get a better time with a slower speed, unless the course got shorter.

Comment: 15 mph is far too slow for the question which was posed - I can do 18 and I'm just some wally who doesn't even use his drops.

Comment: 24 km/h on flat terrain on a road bike is a *very* slow target for someone who wants to be a better than average cyclist, as is said in the question. I'd say 30 km/h is the absolute minimum for someone who is at least a little bit ambitious and thinking of entering more-or-less serious races.

Comment: @RoelSchroeven  any speed is better than none.  Simply finding the mindset to take part in a race is the single biggest road block.  This focus on "being better than average" means OP might never get over the start line let alone a finish line.

Comment: @npostavs yeah that bit makes little sense in re-reading.  Probably I got to the first race sooner and hung about longer.  Both races were the same course but wildly different weather conditions.

Comment: @HenryS Even being dead-last in a race is still better than Did Not Finish, which is still better than Did Not Start.   Racing has a lot of tactics to it in the event, and I think some of that leaks out into the real world.  IE mindgames of discouraging competition.  We have to be welcoming and encouraging, not gatekeepers rejecting newbies with "you have to ride 30 km/h to be `good enough` to enter"

Comment: Remember you're totally welcome to add your own answers to the question.